# In MongoDB 2.6 $maxScan not working with $text query

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB db with a text index. I want to limit the number of documents scanned when doing a text search for performance's sake. However, both:

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"something"}}).explain()
```

and

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"something"}})._addSpecial({"$maxScan":1}).explain()
```

give me the same results:

```
{
    "cursor": "TextCursor",
    "n": 6672,
    "nscannedObjects": 6672,
    "nscanned": 6672,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans": 6672,
    "nscannedAllPlans": 6672.
    "scanAndOrder": false,
    "nYields": 104,
    "nChunkSkips": 0,
    ...
}
```

Shouldn't the second query only scan a single document? More generally, how can I ensure that my search is not going to take a long time, assuming the use of limit() doesn't solve the problem?

When I try the same with another non-text query, though, it works as expected.

I'm using MongoDB 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be documented as such but this is logically by design.

While there has been quite a lot of work into unifying the Index API, (and hence the now similar query structure) things like "text" and "geo-spatial" indexes are really not the same as the general B-Tree cousins.

The whole purpose of both of those types is for a sort of "fuzzy matching" logic, that finds things that are "close to" or "like" the terms given in the query.

As such there is not really an analog to a "restriction" on the number of entries scanned, well not for "text" indexes anyway. With "geo" type queries there is often a concept of a "maxDistance" that can be used to define a limitation on "how far away" a "near" point can be considered.

But for text there is no real built-in stopper for restricting the matched "terms", which as pointed out at the start, is actually different from a restriction on a linear scan.

Text indexes are young in MongoDB, there may be some functionality for this in the future, but just like with "geo" it is not likely to be `$maxScan` but some other specialized term instead.

If you need better performance, then look into a "full blown" text search solution external to MongoDB.